# How to Distinct one column from all the column in SAS SQL

Tags: sql, sas

[enter image description here]

[image: 1]

For Example in below table, I need output with same name and ID and different code

```
Name    ID  Code
Tom     1   155
Tom     1   165
Tom     2   166
Tom     2   166
Tom     3   128
Tom     4   999
```

Below is the required Output

```
Name    ID  Code
Tom     1   155
Tom     1   165
```

Comment: You need to `group by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GROUP BY and HAVING.

First let's convert your example listing into an actual dataset.

```
data have; 
 input Name $ ID Code;
cards;
Tom     1   155
Tom     1   165
Tom     2   166
Tom     2   166
Tom     3   128
Tom     4   999
;
```

So group by NAME and ID and only keep the cases where there are more than one distinct value of CODE.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
    select *
    from have 
    group by name,id
    having count(distinct code) > 1
  ;
quit;
```

Results:

```
Obs    Name    ID    Code

 1     Tom      1     165
 2     Tom      1     155
```

Answer (score 1):

ok , one ways is using window functions

```
select Name, Id, Code
from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by Name,Id,Code order by code desc) rn
   from table
) t
where t.rn > 1
```

Comment: I need distinct for different code with has same Name and ID

Comment: @Andybirada , ok I see , updated my answer ,

Comment: Wouldn't that eliminate the first of multiple distinct codes?

Answer (score 1):

Partition the rows by `Name` and `ID`, then find what the `MIN(Code)` and `MAX(Code)` are in each partition.  If they're different, they're what you want.

```
WITH
  partitioned
AS
(
  SELECT
    yourTable.*,
    MIN(Code) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Code)  AS MinCode,
    MAX(Code) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Code)  AS MaxCode
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  partitioned
WHERE
  MinCode <> MaxCode
```

Comment: That cannot work in SAS since PROC SQL does not support windowing functions.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.id = t.id and t2.code <> t.code
             );
```

As a bonus, this is compatible with `proc sql`.

For performance, you can create an index:

```
proc sql;
    create index idx_t_name_id_code on t(name, id, code);
```

Comment: Thanks , When I'm using Proc Sql , it's taking forever to create the dataset for 400,000 records. I'm getting the output as expected which is good . Is anything we can do to run the code more efficiently . thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in SAS, just use `proc sort`.

```
proc sort data=have out=want nodupkey;
    by name id;
run;
```